# Gradle using different abiFilters for debug and release

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, ndk-build

here's a piece of my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    //...

    defaultConfig {
        //...

        externalNativeBuild {

                ndkBuild {
                    targets "MyGame"
                    arguments "NDK_MODULE_PATH=$cocospath:$cocospath/cocos:$cocospath/external:$cocospath/cocos/prebuilt-mk:$cocospath/extensions"
                    arguments "-j" + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

                    buildTypes {
                        debug {
                            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
                        }

                        release {
                            abiFilters "armeabi"
                        }
                    }

                }
        }
    }
    //.........
```

I'm trying to use three abi filters `(armeabi, armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a)` while building app in debug mode and use only one `(armeabi)` while building release apk. But it doesn't work. Either debug and release version are using all three abiFilters.

What's wrong with my gradle file?

edit:

It turns out when I had all three abi filters and successfully build app I wanted to leave just armeabi and... still all three were added. I had to manually delete contents of app/build directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You put your a**abiFIlters** in a wrong block. This is how it will work:

```
android {
  //...

  defaultConfig {
    //...

    externalNativeBuild {
      ndkBuild {
         targets "MyGame"
         arguments …
      }
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
       ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
  }
}
```